# Myanmar: A viable topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

There are plenty of questions surrounding the conflict with the leader of the country claiming some of the pictures we have seen are staged elsewhere, claims that village fires were started by the Rohingya themselves and that the Rohingya were planting explosives and this response is against terrorists or the [UN claim that this is a 'textbook' case of 'ethnic clensing'](http://www.abc.net.au/news/2017-09-11/un-decries-ethnic-cleansing-in-myanmar/8893450).

Whilst there is a lot of uncertainty on these questions I'm not sure whether any of these are suitible for this stackexchange (or can even be answered anywhere), I thought it best to check here first before posting on the main page.

Comment: Probably not yet viable

Comment: About those 'setting fire' claims: http://observers.france24.com/en/20170911-burmese-authorities-create-posed-photos-frame-rohingya-violence. Would the work done by observers.france24 be specific enough as an answer? (Note that at the bottom of that post there's that same UN link).

Answer (score 7):

Apart from the normal requirements of a specific claim and notability (i.e. that many people believe the claim), we also have a restriction on events that are so recent that there has been insufficient time for journalists, officials and other investigative bodies to determine what happened. Sometimes, we just have to wait to find out what happened.

This seems to be the main discussion of this issue: [Handling news questions about current events](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/handling-news-questions-about-current-events)

Comment: *"Sometimes, we just have to wait to find out what happened."* Just to be clear, are you saying that this is the case for the topic at hand?

Comment: @Anders: I am not sufficiently familiar with the situation in Myanmar right now to make a call. In any case, I wrote this two weeks ago, so the situation (in terms of the depth of coverage, and the facts now ascertained) may well have changed in the meantime.