# Is Moderna a pump-and-dump?

Tags: discussion

How can [Is Moderna a pump-and-dump?](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/48297) be edited, improved, to be re-opened? It was closed by merely 2 votes from Daniel R Hicks, fredsbend♦. But I'm uncertain if [fredsbend♦'s comment](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/48297/is-moderna-a-pump-and-dump) is correct.

> It won't be fraud or pump and dump until they actually commit the crime. This is a current event. – [fredsbend♦](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/users/11643/fredsbend) [4 hours ago](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/48297/is-moderna-a-pump-and-dump#comment225574_48297)

I replied

> @fredsbend I'm not seeking "a technical analysis." "It won't be fraud or pump and dump until they actually commit the crime." Pumping and dumping isn't necessarily a crime, and can be happening now as we speak if insiders deliberately buy low and sell high without creating anything useful

Comment: Undeleted; self-deleting good content is seen as vandalism.

Answer (score 7):

It's a pedantic point, hidden by the bigger issues, but the title is confused: A [pump and dump](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pump_and_dump) isn't a *company*, it is a type of fraud committed by individuals.

None of the quotes use the words "pump and dump". SecForm4.com doesn't claim it. Cramer doesn't claim it, etc. So the claim isn't notable yet. Find someone making the claim.

Answer (score 2):

If it's happening "right now as we speak", it's very clearly a current event. That's the major issue with the question. From [the meta post defining the no current events policy](https://skeptics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2868/handling-news-questions-about-current-events/2870#2870):

> the evidence available in determining the answer changes rapidly. What appears to be the correct answer today may be proven wrong by information discovered tomorrow.

That's a serious problem for this format. I only suggested "technical analysis" on Money SE so that you can still seek an answer that satisfies you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. We could focus on Moderna's past insider sellings, to narrow the subject?

Comment: @Accounting Only if someone makes a claim about that and you have reason to be skeptical of the claim.